# Error App Domains: buydirect.za.com is not a valid domain

Tags: facebook, subdomain

I keep on getting the same anwer when I try to submit my site. This only happens with `.za.com`. Does anyone have a fix for this? Thanks.

Error:

> App Domains: buydirect.za.com is not a valid domain.

Answer (score 0):

That is because .ZA.COM isn't a real top level domain (TLD). Examples of a real TLD would be .COM or .CO.ZA.

ZA.COM is a trick where [CentralNic](https://www.centralnic.com/) bought the domain ZA.COM from the .COM registrar and then is using sub-domains off the ZA.COM domain on that to offer a top level domain like service.

No fix I am afraid other than change domains or contact Facebook to see if they can white list ZA.COM.

Comment: Thanks Robert,any idea what the best way is to contact them.Or do you perhaps know off a third party that can do something like this even if they charge a fee thats fine.

Comment: Only way I can think of to get hold of them is through: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs